# How to stop initial render for useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Earlier I had a Class component, so I didn't face any issues while using lifecycle methods, but after converting to useEffect hooks, I am facing the initial render issue which I don't want to happen.

**Class**

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        patchVal:this.props.patchTaskVal,
        startTime:this.props.patchStartTime,
        setEndTime:this.props.patchEndTime
    })
}
    
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.patchTaskVal !== this.props.patchTaskVal) {
        this.callValidation()
    }

    if (prevProps.closeTask !== this.props.closeTask) {
        this.setState({
            showValue:false,
            progressValue:[],
            startTime:new Date(),
            setEndTime:""
        })
    }

    if (prevProps.patchStartTime !== this.props.patchStartTime || prevProps.endTime !== this.props.endTime && this.props.endTime !== "") {
        this.setState({
            startTime:this.props.patchStartTime,
            setEndTime:parseInt(this.props.endTime)
        })
    }
}
```

**Functional**

```
const [patchTaskVal, setPatchTaskVal]=useState(/*initial value */) 
const [startTime, setStartTime]=useState()
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState()
    
**// I want only this useEffect to run on the initial render**
useEffect(() => {
    setPatchTaskVal(props.patchTaskVal)
    ...//set other states
}, [])
    
useEffect(() => {
    callValidation() 
}, [props.patchTaskVal])
    
useEffect(() => {
    //setShowValue...
}, [props.closeTask])
    
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.endTime != "") {
        // set states...
    }
}, [props.patchStartTime,props.endTime])
```

Here I am facing an issue where all the useEffects are running on the initial render, Please suggest a solution for this so that only the first useEffect will run on the initial render and all other useEffects will run according to its dependency prop values.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Etheryte, On initial render I will be setting up some values, and later  in the application according to the conditions and the prop values I will set new values, but here every useEffect is running on initial render, so that like function calls everything is getting on very first render itself which I don't want it to happen.

Comment: Seems odd you want that behavior, But you can make if statement that makes the useEffect not run if first render then update it when you want it to render

Answer (score 1):

You basically need a `ref` which will tell you whether this is the first render on not. Refs values persist over rerenders. You can start with a `truthy` value and toggle it to `false` after the first render (using a `useEffect` with an empty array[]). Based on that you can run your desired code.

You can also put the whole thing in a custom hook:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useOnUpdate = (callback, deps) => {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFirst.current) {
      callback();
    }
  }, deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    isFirst.current = false;
  }, []);
};

export default useOnUpdate;
```

You can call this hook in your component like :

```
  useOnUpdate(() => {
    console.log(prop);
  }, [prop]);
```

In the hook:
After the initial render, both `useEffect`s run. But when the first effect runs the value of the `isFirst.current` is true. So the callback is not called. The second `useEffect` also runs and sets `isFirst.current` to false.
Now in subsequent renders only the first `useEffect` run (when dependencies change), and `isFirst.current` is false now so `callback` is executed.

The order of the two `useEffects` is very important here. Otherwise, in the `useEffect` with `deps`, `isFirst.current` will be true even after the first render.

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-jennings-p2b60x?file=/hooks/useOnUpdate.js:0-293)

Comment: Could you please explain, I tried the same way but without using the custom hooks, please view this, [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-lederberg-wk97d6?file=/src/App.js), But still I am getting it wrong?

Comment: Do let me know which part do you not explain in my answer. Look at this sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-feistel-81l5wf?file=/src/App.js Please explain what are you trying to achieve, it is a little difficult to understand

Comment: That custom hook, and what will be the flow on the initial render bud?

Comment: I tried to better the explanation @Madhan1021. Have a look

Comment: Thanks bro, I understood now, I will give it a try for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the functional and the class component you can notice that there is one part missing - previous props.

Functional component does not have previous props in scope, but you can save them yourself with a small trick: save them to reference so it will not impact you render cycle.

Since now you have the previous props and the current props you can apply the same logic you did for class component.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [commitInput, setCommitInput] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={() => setCommitInput(input)}>apply</button>
      <Child test={commitInput} />
    </>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  const prev = useRef(props.test);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (prev.current !== props.test) {
      alert("only when changes");
    }
  }, [props.test]);

  return <div>{props.test}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
let init = true;
useEffect( ()=>{
if(init) {

    setPatchTaskVal(props.patchTaskVal)
init = false;
    ...//set other states}
}, [])

useEffect( ()=> {

    !init && callValidation() 
},[props.patchTaskVal])

useEffect( ()=>{
//!init && setShowValue...
},[props.closeTask])

useEffect( ()=>{
    if(props.endTime!="" && !init){
    // set states...
    }
},[props.patchStartTime,props.endTime])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope my understanding is right about your question.
Why not just add a `if statement` to check the `state` is not `undefined` or `default value`

```js
useEffect( ()=> {
  if (props.patchTaskVal) {
    callValidation() 
  }
},[props.patchTaskVal])

useEffect( ()=>{
  if (props.closeTask) {
    //setShowValue...  
  }
},[props.closeTask])

useEffect( ()=>{
    if(props.patchStartTime){
    // set states...
    }
    
    if(props.endTime){
    // set states...
    }
},[props.patchStartTime,props.endTime]
```

---

And according your class component,

```js
this.setState({
patchVal:this.props.patchTaskVal,
startTime:this.props.patchStartTime,
setEndTime:this.props.patchEndTime
})
```

The function component should map props to component's state. Like this

```js
const [patchTaskVal, setPatchTaskVal]=useState(props.patchTaskVal) 
const [startTime, setStartTime]=useState(props.patchStartTime)
const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState(props.patchEndTime)
```

Comment: So, is it not possible to set directly the props as a dependency array?

Comment: It is possible, I wrote that example just because your class component